# UITextView resignFirstResponder Crash on Back

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview

I'm doing a form on my app with a `UITextView` and resigning it when user scrolls on the `UIScrollView` behind it.

Code:

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if ([self.messageBox canResignFirstResponder]) {
        [self.messageBox resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

When I click in the text view, edit, then resign by scrolling around, I click on the Back button of my `NavigationController` and then the app crashes with:

```
[BugReportViewController scrollViewDidScroll:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x157518390
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Does your app crash if you don't do anything on this controller, but just hit the back button?

Comment: @Stonz2 If I go on the textview trying to edit something and then resign by scrolling (and calling `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`) and then, the crash occurs when i hit the Back button. Any other action will not crash the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the scroll view is sending a message to its delegate after the delegate has been deallocated. To fix this, override `dealloc` in the view controller that owns the text view, and set the scroll view's `delegate` property to `nil`.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much :) So I added `-(void)dealloc {[self.scroller setDelegate:nil];}`